# Is it recommended to set IdleTimeout as zero in ActiveMQ PooledConnectionFactory?

Tags: activemq-artemis

Is it recommended to set IdleTimeout as zero in ActiveMQ `PooledConnectionFactory`? We use ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0 as our JMS broker and the ActiveMQ JMS pool 5.16.2 as connection pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general recommendation with tunable parameters like this is to start with the default and adjust as needed based on your specific use-case.

With an idleTimeout of `0` no connection will ever be considered idle. Typically you *wouldn't* want this because your pool would never shrink down from its maximum size. Typically a pool is used to make efficient use of the connections and specifically to avoid creating too many connections when load is high. As the application load increases and decreases the pool typically will grow and shrink as well. This prevents the application from overwhelming the back-end service (i.e. the broker in this case) and/or consuming connection resources when they aren't actually needed. If idleTimeout is `0` the pool will never shrink down after application load increases and then decreases again requiring fewer connections. As noted previously, typically this isn't what you'd want, but perhaps this behavior fits your use-case perfectly.

Aside from the configuration, there *is* a general recommendation to use [the Messaging Hub PooledJMS implementation](https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms) instead of the one directly from the ActiveMQ "Classic" code-base like you're using. This is because ActiveMQ Artemis has full support for JMS 2, and the connection pool implementation from ActiveMQ "Classic" *does not*. The Messaging Hub PooledJMS implementation was forked from the one in the ActiveMQ "Classic" code-base and modified to support JMS 2 as well as a few other updates.

Comment: With default value as 30 seconds, in between `createConnection` is taking more time in 1-2 seconds which I want to avoid. Is it recommended to set `setMaxConnections` as `1` and `idleTimeout` as zero?

Comment: There's no specific recommendation to set maxConnections to `1` and idleTimeout to `0`. As noted previously, the general recommendation is to start with the default and adjust as needed based on your specific use-case. You haven't provided many details about your use-case and what problem you're trying to solve so it's really impossible to provide specific guidance.